# android service to keep track of outgoing calls and SMS in background

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to write a service in android which will keep track of outgoing calls and SMS in background. Whenever an outgoing call event or outgoing SMS event is received, I want to fetch the details like phone number, date, call duration (in case of outgoing call) and cost of call or SMS. I want to save these details in local database.

I tried using broadcast receiver along with services, but I am not able to calculate the actual call duration. And for SMS I found out that we need to check the SMS folder after some particular time period whether it is updated. Is there any event which will notify after the SMS is sent.

Following is the Code I have tried so far-

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView call = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        call = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }
}
```

My Service Class

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
      CallDurationReceiver receiver = null;


      @Override
      public void onCreate() {

          receiver = new CallDurationReceiver();

          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
          filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
          filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
          registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

          HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments");
        thread.start();

      }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
          return START_STICKY;
      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { 
          // We don't provide binding, so return null
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
          unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      }
}
```

My Broadcast receiver -

```
public class CallDurationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // instance variables of sharedpreferences
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefernce;
    Editor e;

    // String variables for number,date,time,calltype
    String number, date, time, calltype;
    long startTime, endTime;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("info", "calls info....");

        // initialising the sharedpreferences
        mSharedPrefernce = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        e = mSharedPrefernce.edit();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null)
            return;

        // initialising the variables
        number = null;
        startTime = 0;
        endTime = 0;

        // getting incoming call details
        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if ((state != null)
                && (state
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {

            Log.v("info", "Phone Ringing..");

            number = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.v("info", "Incomng Number: " + number);

            calltype = "Incoming";

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();

            date = today.monthDay + "-" + (today.month + 1) + "-" + today.year;
            time = today.format("%k:%M:%S");

            // putting the values into the SharedPreferences
            e.putString("number", number);
            e.putString("Type", calltype);
            e.putString("date", date);
            e.putString("time", time);
            e.commit();

            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: "
                            + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        // getting outgoing call details
        else if (state == null) {
            number = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.v("info", "Outgoing Number: " + number);

            calltype = "Outgoing";

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();

            date = today.monthDay + "-" + (today.month + 1) + "-" + today.year;
            time = today.format("%k:%M:%S");

            // putting the values into the SharedPreferences
            e.putString("number", number);
            e.putString("Type", calltype);
            e.putString("date", date);
            e.putString("time", time);
            e.commit();

            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Detect Calls sample application\nOutgoing number: "
                            + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        // called when the call is answered
        else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Log.v("info", "Call Ansered..");

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            e.putLong("start", startTime);
            e.commit();

        } 
        // called when the call is ended
        else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.v("info", "Call Ended..");

            String phonenumber=null, type=null, date1=null, time1=null,  duration=null;

            // getting the values from the SharedPreferences
            phonenumber = mSharedPrefernce.getString("number", "");
            type = mSharedPrefernce.getString("Type", "");
            date1 = mSharedPrefernce.getString("date", "");
            time1 = mSharedPrefernce.getString("time", "");
            long start=0;
            start = mSharedPrefernce.getLong("start", 0);
            Log.v("info", "startTime=" + start);

            // clearing the SharedPreferences
            mSharedPrefernce.edit().clear();

            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.v("info", "endTime=" + endTime);
            long totalTime =0;
            totalTime = endTime - start;

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH':'mm':'ss");
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));

            duration = df.format(new Date(totalTime));

            System.out.println("GOT SOMETHING - "+phonenumber + " " + date1 + " " + time1 + " " + duration + " " + type);

            Toast.makeText(context, phonenumber + " " + date1 + " " + time1 + " " + duration + " " + type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }

}
```

and the Manifest File -

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sumasoft.mb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.sumasoft.mb.HelloService" >
        </service>

       <receiver android:name=".CallDurationReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
```

I even tried fetching the last outgoing call details from call log but I get the all calls, I just need the last outgoing call.

here is the code -

```
 private String getCallDetails() {

              StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
              Cursor managedCursor = MainActivity.managedCursor;
              int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
              int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
              int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
              int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
              sb.append( "Call Details :");
              while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
              String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
              String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
              String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
              Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
              String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
              String dir = null;
              int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
              switch( dircode ) {
              case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
              dir = "OUTGOING";
              break;

              case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
              dir = "INCOMING";
              break;

              case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
              dir = "MISSED";
              break;
              }
              sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
              sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
              }
              managedCursor.close();
              return sb.toString();
              }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, Did you get any solution for outgoing call tracking?

Comment: Actually I shifted to a different logic. I queried call log for latest call details when the call gets over.

some reference - 

int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( allLog.Calls.DURATION);       

Write this inside broadcast receiver.

Comment: Can I have your code?

Comment: Sure. Please give me your mail id.

Comment: Thanks very good code, but in this line:  Cursor managedCursor = MainActivity.managedCursor;
how can I create this managedCursor?
and If you can please send me the code I will appreciate it @ aziz.egy@gmail.com

Comment: @rupalimandge can you please send me the code. I am also looking for it. Bundle of thanks.